# STL structure inside Shared Memory

Tags: c++, visual-c++, shared-memory

I need to create a queue like structure inside my structure which I use as shared memory. How can I do this ? My compiler is Visual C++.

Comment: Try Boost.Interprocess.

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/interprocess/allocators_containers.html

Comment: isnt it possible without using external libraries ?

Comment: is it really memory shared by different process ?

Comment: yes. One process will create a shared memory and put integers to the queue. and another one will read them.

Comment: Everything is possible without external libraries, you just may have to do a lot more work, that was already done by someone else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a complex C++ object within shared memory is not so simple I fear. You have to consider two things.

1)

You need to create the class instance in the shared memory area instead of on the stack. You can to this by using the placement new operator. Example:

```
#include <new> // for placement new operator

class X
{
     // whatever
};

// suppose this points to some shared memory area
void *shared_mem = getSharedMem();

// this creates an instance of X at the start address of shared_mem
new(shared_mem) X;

// now you have a reference to an instance of X in the shared memory area
X& shared_x = *reinterpret_cast<X*>(shared_mem);
```

Note, however, that only one process should be responsible for constructing that object in shared memory. Also the other processes participating need a means to know whether the object is already correctly initialized and can be safely accessed. Access also requires some kind of inter-process locking (on Win32 a named mutex, for example)

2)

If your class type requires dynamic memory like it is the case with a queue data structure then the memory can't come from the heap as usual, because the heap is local to one process. If you'd like to use an STL queue container then you can implement your own STL allocator class that gets its memory not from the heap but from shared memory.

The allocator class used is part of the STL template declaration. For example std::deque<T, A> where A is the allocator type. By default the standard STL allocator is used that gets its memory from the heap.

Your custom shared-memory allocator would then need to know from what shared memory address exactly the memory can be allocated. The allocator support in most STL implementations doesn't play very well with per-instance data of allocators (as to my knowledge) so you'd probably need some global/static data in the allocator such that it can know where to get shared memory from.

All in all you might be better off to write a simple custom queue class that operates on shared memory like described in 1). You could make the queue class use statically sized memory for example it could hold space for exactly 100 objects in the queue and if you exceed this limit then the operation fails.

Comment: How can another process reach an object in shared memory ? (Assuming the object has been successfully initialized and other process knows the address of shared memory)

Answer (score 0):

1. Use a [mutex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion) to protect your shared memory, whatever data type or class it may be. It doesn't matter how complex your data is. Also read this about [how mutexes work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11770571/how-do-mutexes-really-work) and the [wikipedia Threads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_%28computing%29) article. Your shared data has to be in the heap or as a global variable, but not on the stack i.e. not a local variable.
2. For all access of the data, you have to:

   - lock mutex
   - copy data out or write to data (don't spend too much time here)
   - release mutex
   - use data (if copied out)
3. Do you want to use a lightweight, open source, multiplatform C++ library for threads and mutexes? Try [TinyThread++](http://tinythreadpp.bitsnbites.eu/). Its license is also suitable for commercial use, being free permissive. It consists of 3 files only. Please refer to the documentation on how to use it. The C version is [TinyCThread](http://tinycthread.bitsnbites.eu/).